# OpenCart Filtergroup Dropdown

Tags: php, opencart

How can I make a dropdown for a specific filtergroup id only?
I need the other filtergroups to stay like the default list.

On template/module/filter.tpl

I have added

```
<select id="select-filter-group<?php echo $filter_group['filter_group_id']; ?>">
        <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
        <?php foreach ($filter_group['filter'] as $filter) { ?>
          <?php if (in_array($filter['filter_id'], $filter_category)) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $filter['name']; ?></option>
          <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>"><?php echo $filter['name']; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
```

This works but makes every filtergroup into a dropdown, 
I just need Filter Group ID 4 (exmaple) to be a dropdown and the other stays as before.

How can this be done?

OpenCart 1.5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, very simply, use a condition around Your select:

```
<?php if($filter_group['filter_group_id'] == 4) { ?>
  <select id="select-filter-group<?php echo $filter_group['filter_group_id']; ?>">
    <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
    <?php foreach ($filter_group['filter'] as $filter) { ?>
      <?php if (in_array($filter['filter_id'], $filter_category)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $filter['name']; ?></option>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>"><?php echo $filter['name']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
<?php } else { ?>
<!-- the default code for filter groups goes here -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will only show a ID 4 dropdown and nothing else, I want to keep the other ID's as the default list and only make ID 4 as a dropdown.

Comment: Have You ever done some PHP? Or other programming? Of course this exact code will only show Filter group with ID 4, but it is up to You to use the default code as well... Check my edited answer... This site is not COPY+PASTE, You should also think at least a little...

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I had a vQmod file replacing things in that file, that's why it didn't work at first. Of course I know it's not copy&paste, appreciate all help I got.